reusable custom component in react hook form
so um I've been trying to make a reusable Input component so I don't have to copy paste all of the styles everywhere and I made this
import { FieldValues, UseFormRegister, Path } from 'react-hook-form';
interface Props<T extends FieldValues> {
  label: string;
  id: keyof T;
  type?: string;
  register: UseFormRegister<T>;
  error?: string;
}

const FormField = <T extends FieldValues>({
  label,
  id,
  type = 'text',
  register,
  error,
}: Props<T>) => {
  return (
    <div className='flex flex-col gap-4 border p-2'>
      <label className='font-bold' htmlFor={id as string}>
        {label}
      </label>
      <input type={type} id={id as string} {...register(id as Path<T>)} />
      {error && <span className='text-red-500'>{error}</span>}
    </div>
  );
};

export default FormField;

But I feel like this is not the right way to do it or maybe it is at this point I don't know. if anyone has built a similar component I would appreciate help and suggestion

you are on the right track. This is exactly what you should be doing

Since you already know you'll be using react-hook-form to implement your reusable input, you can make it an internal dependency with useFormContext; this way there's less data to pass with props.
You can also add type-safety to your Props.type field.
Updated code below:
import { HTMLInputTypeAttribute as InputType } from "react";
import { FieldValues, Path, get, useFormContext } from "react-hook-form";

interface Props<T extends FieldValues, K extends InputType> {
  label: string;
  type?: K;
  id: Path<T>;
}

const FormField = <T extends FieldValues, K extends InputType = InputType>({
  label,
  id,
  type = "text" as K,
}: Props<T, K>) => {
  const {
    register,
    formState: { errors },
  } = useFormContext<T>();

  const error = get(errors, id)?.message;

  return (
    <div className="flex flex-col gap-4 border p-2">
      <label className="font-bold" htmlFor={id}>
        {label}
      </label>
      <input type={type} id={id} {...register(id)} />
      {error && <span className="text-red-500">{error}</span>}
    </div>
  );
};

export default FormField;


My solution is using zod for validation and typings codesandbox Just make sure to wrap your components in a form provider.
<FormProvider {...form}>
    <form onSubmit={form.handleSubmit((data) => console.log(data))}>
      <FormInput control={form.control} name="first" label="First Name" />
      ...rest of inputs

To make the name type safe you can use the form control like this.
import {
  useController,
  type FieldValues,
  type Path,
  type UseControllerProps,
} from "react-hook-form";

/**
 * A utility type that requires the `control` prop from `react-hook-form` while still allowing other props to be optional.
 */
type RequiredControl<TFieldValues extends FieldValues = FieldValues> = Required<
  Pick<UseControllerProps<TFieldValues>, "control">
> &
  UseControllerProps<TFieldValues>;

/**
 * A type that uses the `name` and `control` prop to make the field name type safe
 */
export type FormFieldWithName<TFieldValues extends FieldValues = FieldValues> =
  RequiredControl<TFieldValues> & {
    name: Path<TFieldValues>;
  };

/**
 * Base input props
 */
type InputProps = React.InputHTMLAttributes<HTMLInputElement>;

/**
 * Component props
 */
type Props<TFieldValues extends FieldValues = FieldValues> =
  FormFieldWithName<TFieldValues> &
    InputProps & {
      label: string;
      labelClassName?: string;
    };

/**
 * Reusable Form Input component
 */
export const FormInput = <T extends FieldValues = FieldValues>({
  label,
  labelClassName,
  name,
  ...props
}: Props<T>) => {
  const { field } = useController({ name });

  return (
    <div className="wrapper">
      <label htmlFor={name} className={labelClassName}>
        {label}
      </label>
      <input {...field} {...props} />
    </div>
  );
};

